# XAMPP write permission

Tags: installation, permissions, xampp, uac

I have installed the XAMPP, then it raised a UAC problem. Because of this the XAMPP is unable to write.

I tried to turn off the UAC and reinstall the XAMPP but the warning was still there. Next I tried to change the location but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Change the permissions on the folder that XAMPP is trying to write to, and grant <kbd>Everyone</kbd> **Full Control** to the folder.